# mysql aggregate from derived table

Tags: mysql

The product of a GROUPAGE mysql query is a table like so;

```
id      group      amount1      amount2
01      A          500
01      B          340
01      C          190
02      A                       270
02      B                       440
02      C                       110
```

Now i want to perform a new query on this result and my expected output is to be so;

```
group      amount1      amount2
A          500          270
B          340          440
C          190          110
```

If i make the former a derived table T in my query, how is the integral query to look if i must achieve such result.

I realise this may not be a complex query, bt i'm still catching up on mysql syntax. Help pls.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though description not too clear, I suppose you use smth like `group by with rollup`

So to achieve the result you want you can use such syntax

```
select
   `group`,
    sum(amount1),
    sum(amount2)
from
    ( your query that creates derived table) as t
group by 
    `group`
```

You could also use MAX or MIN if it's enough for you(actually any aggregation function)

Comment: Seeing your answer helped alot. I was already on track but i dint use the SUM() in my integral query so it was picking one row only from my derived table. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a self join? Syntax not checked, but something like this?

```
SELECT 
    d1.`group`, d1.`amount1`, d2.`amount2` 
FROM derivedtable as d1
JOIN derivedtable as d2 ON d1.`group` = d2.`group`;
```

You could also potentially do a GROUP BY?

```
SELECT `group`, max(`amount1`), max(`amount2`) FROM `derivedtable` GROUP BY `group`;
```

The max aggregate function will force the first non-null value.

Comment: The self join was kind tricky to implement for me, bt the group by works fine.